# Load iframe using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I have a use case where I want to load an iframe having `src` as dynamically generated. I can load this URL using `res.redirect('https://example.org')`. But my problem statement is like. Once I load this page, I am not able to do `res.send` or `res.render` etc because node.js won't allow **redirects after sending the response to the client**.

So I need a mechanism where I can load dynamically this URL in already defined iframe. And then easily, I should be able to handle any redirects.

[EDIT] : So my flow on the applications is
Click on a button -> Do an API call from node js to fetch access token -> Do another api call to get dynamic URL -> Load the URL in iframe.

Again re-iterating I simply cannot do `res.redirect` to load the url in window, because after this I wont be able to do `res.send` etc. because node.js does not allow you to do this

Comment: Why not make another call from the client to fetch the iframe data that you need?

Comment: So the flow is : click a button -> do some api call to get access toke etc -> another api call to fetch dynamic URL -> load the URL @tomer

Comment: "because after this I wont be able to do res.send etc" — Why would you want to do that after redirecting?

Comment: @Quentin because I want to show the result of an API.. and the above iframe url is loaded as a widget.. and I don't have any control on the widget

Comment: So you don't want to show the page you are redirecting to … you want to show a **modified** version of the page you are redirecting to with additional data added that you are fetching from an API?

Comment: @Quentin yes exactly.. a page rendered from my app instead of the widget

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an existing HTML document with modifications then you can't just redirect to it. You will need to:

1. Get that HTML document (e.g. with `axios`)
2. Parse it (e.g. with `cheerio`)
3. Modify it (probably also with `cheerio`)

   - You will need to make the modifications you want
   - You may need to make other changes (e.g. updating relative URLs) since you will be serving the HTML document from a different URL
4. `send` that modified HTML document back to the client

Alternatively, you could use client-side JavaScript to modify the document in the browser. This would probably involve making two HTTP requests (one for the data to modify it with and the other for the original HTML document) and might be restricted by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: But how and where do I load my widget ? And what happens when I want to close the widget and show some API result ?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with your question. (Or what you mean by "widget". Or why you need know how to close your own widget - if you designed it you built the close functionality. Or what that has to do with displaying data from the API - you make an HTTP request then modify the DOM.) (Probably. You're using extremely generic terms which make less and less sense in context).

Comment: It's a third-party widget. I don't have any control over it. It just displays you a form. You fill it. Once after filling you make yet another API call to get some result. This result you should display on your own app by getting rid of the widget.. I hope it makes sense now ?